# Календарь Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы календарь Windows из таскбара не закрывался после клика по другому месту? Пытался искать решение, так и не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно конечно, для этого достаточно разобрать приложение, изменить обработку потери фокуса и собрать обратно :) вас же именно такой метод интересовал раз вопрос задан на сайте программирования?

Comment: Любые способы. Хотя вернее было бы задать вопрос по типу как найти дескриптор окна этих часов. Моя ошибка

Comment: ну если только поиск дескриптора, то держите ответ... ЯП вы не называли, буду волен выбирать сам :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По просьбе из комментария:
Поиск дескриптора активного окна(Golang):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
    mod                     = windows.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procGetWindowText       = mod.NewProc("GetWindowTextW")
    procGetWindowTextLength = mod.NewProc("GetWindowTextLengthW")
)

type (
    HANDLE uintptr
    HWND   HANDLE
)

func GetWindowTextLength(hwnd HWND) int {
    ret, _, _ := procGetWindowTextLength.Call(
        uintptr(hwnd))

    return int(ret)
}

func GetWindowText(hwnd HWND) string {
    textLen := GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1

    buf := make([]uint16, textLen)
    procGetWindowText.Call(
        uintptr(hwnd),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])),
        uintptr(textLen))

    return syscall.UTF16ToString(buf)
}

func getWindow(funcName string) uintptr {
    proc := mod.NewProc(funcName)
    hwnd, _, _ := proc.Call()
    return hwnd
}

func main() {
    for {
        if hwnd := getWindow("GetForegroundWindow"); hwnd != 0 {
            text := GetWindowText(HWND(hwnd))
            fmt.Println(text,hwnd)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```